# Oculus Rift and Processing 2.0

Tags: processing, oculus

I am trying to get the Oculus Rift working in processing.I am using a library called "SimpleOculusRift" created by the amazing Max Rheiner. However, whenever I run the example sketch I get this error:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
>   Referenced from: /Users/jasontibi/CalArts/Spring
>   2015/Processing/libraries/SimpleOculusRift/library/libSimpleOculusRift.jnilib
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret   Referenced from:
>   /Users/jasontibi/CalArts/Spring
>   2015/Processing/libraries/SimpleOculusRift/library/libSimpleOculusRift.jnilib
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize). For more
>   information, read revisions.txt and Help → Troubleshooting.

I am running Mac OS 10.8.5
I am using Oculus Rift DK1
I am using the latest firmware
and I am on a 64bit intel core i7

Any idea whats happening?
The sketch just crashes and says that processing quit unexpectedly.

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming you mean https://github.com/xohm/SimpleOculusRift, did you build it for OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to upgrade OSX to Yosemite. There was a file that the library used, that only worked in Yosemite because of some native plugin that comes with Yosemite.